# Get the added elements in current json from the previous json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a javascript array stored as json file that looks like this:

```
old_data = [{
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 101
}, {
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 102
}, {
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 103
}]
```

I load it in javascript and another script adds new items to that json file, for example it adds 1 more item so the list becomes

```
new_data = [{
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 101
}, {
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 102
}, {
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 103
}, {
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 104
}]
```

What I want to get is the new items that were added and iterate though them in order to add more elements to html dynamically.

My idea would be check each 5 sec or something similar:

```
<script>
  var previous = null;
  var current = null;
  setInterval(function() {
      $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
          current = JSON.stringify(json);
          if (previous && current && previous !== current) {
              // do stuff              }
          previous = current;
      });
  }, 5000);
</script>
```

and when there is a difference do:

```
var offset = new_data.length - old_data.length;

for(; offset <= new_data.length; offset++) {
    console.log(new_data[offset]);
```

What I noticed is that sometimes the script doesn't get the difference. I have to clear cookies and refresh the page sometimes for it to work. Any solution for this issue? And also, is there a more elegant way of doing this. I'm new to javascript. (I'm not concerned about security since I will be the only one running the scripts locally).

Comment: Much more elegant to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: Order of items does not change?

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee, No, they do not. Basically I will append new items to the original json.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like that by comparisons and using `Array.from`

```js
old_data = [{
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 101
}, {
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 102
}, {
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 103
}]

new_data = [{
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 101
}, {
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 102
}, {
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 103
}, {
  "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg", "weight": 104
}]

var arr1 = Array.from(old_data);
var arr2 = Array.from(new_data);
var blnDiff = false;
var arrDiff = [];
var max = arr1.length;
var maxArr = arr1;
var min = arr2.length;
if(arr1.length < arr2.length || arr2.length < arr1.length) {
blnDiff = true;
}
if(arr2.length > arr1.length){
max = arr2.length;
min = arr1.length;
maxArr = arr2;
}
if(blnDiff){
  for(var i=0;i < max; i++){
    arrDiff[i] = maxArr[min];
  }
}


console.log(arrDiff)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load json file to get updated json file as given below:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var timestamp = date.getTime();
    $.getJSON("data.json?time="+timestamp, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the length of last array in a variable and each time you get data from API, just show from previous length to current length and also update length variable too.

Something like this

```js
let old_data = [{
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 101
  }, {
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 102
  }, {
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 103
  }],
  new_data = [{
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 101
  }, {
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 102
  }, {
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 103
  }, {
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 104
  }, {
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 105
  }, {
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 106
  }, {
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 107
  }, {
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 108
  }, {
    "image": "images/set_1_UTC+03.jpg",
    "weight": 109
  }];

let lengthOfArray = old_data.length,
  htmlText = ``;

setInterval(function() {
  old_data = new_data;
  UpdateBody(lengthOfArray);
  lengthOfArray = old_data.length;
}, 5000);


old_data.forEach(function(itm) {
  htmlText += `<div>Image name: ${itm.image} and weight: ${itm.weight}</div>`;
});

$("#append").html(htmlText);

function UpdateBody(startIndex) {
  for (let i = startIndex; i < old_data.length; i++) {
    htmlText += `<div>Image name: ${old_data[i].image} and weight: ${old_data[i].weight}</div>`;
  }
  $("#append").html(htmlText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="append"></div>
```

Hope it helps you.